# Geocoding to only reference Tileset using Mapbox GL JS?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, mapbox-studio

I'm using Mapbox's Geocoding (search box) and was wondering if there's a way that it would only reference my Tileset data rather than the generic global address search?

Looks like Mapbox has a "[Supplement geocoding search results from another data source](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-geocoder-local-geocoder/)", however the example is referencing geographic coordinates rather than addressing.

I'm still not sure if this is possible?

Basically I want to enter an address in the Geocoding search box and to have a particular polygon selected from my dataset on the map.

Comment: Cross-posted as https://stackoverflow.com/q/49114648/820534

Answer (score 1):

Cross posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49114648/mapbox-gl-js-geocoding-to-only-reference-tileset/49119921

The example you linked to shows how to supplement search results with a local source, not a remote source in the https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder.

Currently Mapbox doesn't provide a Geocoding API against your own data however depending on how large your dataset is (and assuming it's a Mapbox Dataset and not just a Mapbox Tileset) you could use the Datasets API to read in every feature into the client with https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-sdk-js/blob/master/API.md#listfeatures and use the results of that to power the mapbox-gl-geocoder search like https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-geocoder-local-geocoder/